# Close session laravel with id

Tags: php, laravel

How I can close session with id in logout method of auth? In post controller, in method show I set session:

```
 session(["is_model_open_post_id" . $post->id => false]);
```

But when user logout, I need close this session, set true.

```
 session(["is_model_open_post_id" . $post->id => true]);
```

But I don't know How I can get id of post in method logout.

Comment: What does the function `session()` do?

Comment: _But I don't know How I can get id of post in method logout_ Did you keep it anywhere? Maybe in the session array ?

Comment: It seems to me that `$post->id` whatever that is, was not a good thing to concatenate onto the session name

Comment: @RiggsFolly sorry, I fixed. Array of course.

Answer (score 1):

The `session()` helpers argument is used to `get` or `set` session data for the current user. The array function you are using is attempting to again `set` data to the current session.

If I am correct, what you would like to do is `remove` the session data key/value pair entirely.

This can be done with the following method:

```
session()->forget('is_model_open_post_id' . $post->id);
```

If you would like to forget all session data:

```
session()->flush();
```

To take control of what happens when you logout, you will need to update your routingto override the custom `Auth::routes()` logout route:

```
Route::post('logout', function() {
    session()->forget('is_model_open_post_id' . $post->id);

    auth()->logout(); // or Auth::logout();

    return redirect('/'); // or to another route
});
```

**Note:** This should got after `Auth::routes()`.

Comment: How In logout method I can remove session `is_modal_open_post_id` ?

Comment: @Dronax Are you using `Auth::routes()` to use the logout method?

Comment: You will need to override this route I order to add your custom functionality. I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Dronax See answer.

Comment: @Dronax May be a `GET` request I haven't check myself.

Comment: @Dronax Sorry you need to get the `$post` variable, how are you getting it in your controller?